# Parse a port number from the command line

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, port

guys, I am trying to work on a simple chat tcp server that allows messages to be sent back in forth from the server and the client. I have to make it so that the port number is entered in on the command line instead of hardcoded in. I have tried multiple things but this is my most recent effort. I am getting errors about portnum not being an integer, and

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);


s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welocme to the server","utf-8"))
```

and here is what I tried changing it too

```
portnum = input("Enter port number")
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), portnum))
s.listen(5)
```

I have also tried doing :

```
port = sys.argv[1:] and port = int(sys.argv[1])
```

but I keep getting errors and it isn't working

Comment: input returns a string. You need: ‘portnum = int(input("Enter port number"))’

Comment: Thank you very much. Spent an hour just researching this and it ended up being insanely easy:)

Answer (score 1):

`input` will always cast the user's input to a string. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

You should add a check to validate the input is numeric, cast it to an `int` and pass it as the port number.

```
while True:
    portnum = input("Enter port number")
    if portnum.isnumeric():
        portnum = int(portnum)
        s.bind((socket.gethostname(), portnum))
        s.listen(5)
        ...
    else:
        print("Enter a valid port number.")
```